# How we can use Retryable

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have 2 classes.One is Msgcontroller.java and other class is RetryProcess.java

In Msgcontroller.java,I am using the following method

```
public String getSampleService() throws IOException,
            UnsupportedEncodingException, HttpException {
        // Read from request

        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            buffer.append(line);
        }
        String data = buffer.toString();
        StringRequestEntity requestEntity = null;
        StringBuffer eventResponse = new StringBuffer();
        HttpClient httpclient = new HttpClient();
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        int statusCode;
        BufferedReader br = null;
        String jsonReceive = null;
        logger.info("RequestJson" + data);
        baseServiceUrl = "http://localhost:8080/oif";

        apiServiceUrl = "/services/rest/item";

        requestEntity = new StringRequestEntity(data, MEDIA_TYPE, FORMAT);
        PostMethod postMethod = new PostMethod(baseServiceUrl + apiServiceUrl);
        postMethod.setRequestEntity(requestEntity);
        statusCode = httpclient.executeMethod(postMethod);
        logger.info("Status code from item service call" + statusCode);
        inputStream = postMethod.getResponseBodyAsStream();
        if (null != inputStream) {
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, FORMAT));
            for (line = br.readLine(); line != null; line = br.readLine()) {
                eventResponse = eventResponse.append(line);
            }
        }
        jsonReceive = eventResponse.toString();
        logger.info("JsonReceive" + jsonReceive);
        return jsonReceive;
    }
```

And in RetryProcess.java,

```
public class RetryProcess {
    private static final Logger logger  = LogManager.getLogger(RetryProcess.class);
@Retryable(
        value={Exception.class},
        maxAttempts=2,
        backoff=@Backoff(delay=5000)
        )
public void getSplSevice() throws UnsupportedEncodingException, HttpException, IOException{
    Msgcontroller msg=new Msgcontroller ();
    logger.info("Retryprocess");
    msg.getSampleService();
}
}
```

But when an exception occurs in getSampleService() in MsgController ,RetryProcess.java not working.Can anyone help me

Comment: Where is getSplSevice()  called from? It's not shown in your code anywhere. You need to have a controller that is a spring bean, like with `@Controller` annotation, and the RetryProcess also need to be a bean, like with `@Service`. Then when it's called from Msgcontroller, it will retry it. You also need to enable `@Retryable` with `@EnableRetry` on your class that has `@SpringBootApplication`.

Comment: Also a good example here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-retry